# In php how do I set the size of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I just want to set the size of an array in php, without having to fill it up with any values. How do I do that?

Comment: I think there is no such thing. What is the point of this size setting?

Comment: if you told us why you wanted to, there may be an answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/SplFixedArray) for a fixed-size array:

```
$array = new SplFixedArray(3);
$array[0] = 1;
$array[1] = 2;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 4; // RuntimeException
```

Comment: since PHP 5.3. available

Comment: nice function is $array->toArray() if you want to cast the object back to an array

Answer (score 31):

In PHP arrays are really ordered maps and thus have size equal to the number of elements they contain -- if you want to create an empty array of a particular size you're going to have to fill it with something.

You could always fill it with [`null`](http://php.net/null) values using [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill):

```
$empty_arr = array_fill(0, $size, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks. Very useful as an alternative to a for loop to add fillers to a CSV (variable number of fields). A script was throwing an error 200 but a combination of array_fill and implode got around this.

Answer (score 10):

[Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) don't have a set size, they are dynamic (not stored the same as other languages such as C).

If you want to specify an array with a size for performance reasons, look at:

[SplFixedArray](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) in the Standard PHP Library.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add elements to the array to change the size. Whether it is with the value of null, or otherwise.. you must add some element to change the size.